# How to use numpy roots for trig function

Tags: python, numpy

Trying to write some code to find the roots of the function -1.5sin(3x) on the domain [-2, 2]. Is this possible with the numpy roots function?

Essentially the code will look something like this:

```
import numpy as np
def f(x):
  x = -1.5*sin(3*x)
  return x
print(np.roots())
```

I'm just not sure what to put in the parentheses since this function is not a polynomial.

Comment: Nothing has called `f()`

Comment: Surely, it is a polynomial. Check out Taylor series.

Comment: Have a look at the functions in scipy.optimize: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#root-finding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`numpy.roots` needs a polynomial. You do not have one. `numpy.roots` cannot be used to find the roots of an arbitrary function.

Comment: Perhaps you should back up your assertion from [the documenation for numpy.roots](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html).